# I have some problem in this Latex program

Tags: tikz-styles, foreach

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm]
    % some styles
    \tikzset{
      box/.style={
      regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=10mm,
      inner sep=0mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      rotate=0,
      draw
      }
    }
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
      \foreach \j in {0,...,2} {
        \node[box] at (2*\i-1,2*\j-1) {};
        \node[box] at (2*\i,2*\j) {};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

I have some problem in this LaTeX code:

- I want 5 columns, but there are 6 columns here.
- I want only 2 hexagons in the first, third, and fifth columns.
- I want the hexagons in the second row of the second column and the fourth column to be blue. And I want to write numbers 1 and 3 in them.

Is there someone to help, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test as is. For example it is not obvious where the option `regular polygon` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if I understood your question right. Do you mean something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm,
every node/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw,
                     minimum size=10mm, inner sep=0mm, outer sep=0mm}
                    ]
% rows
\foreach \i in {0,1,2}
{
\foreach \j in {0,1,2}
    \node at (2*\j,-2*\i) {};
}
\foreach \j [count=\i from 0,
             evaluate =\j as \k using int(\i+\j)] in {1,2}
{
    \node            at (2*\j-1,-3) {};
    \node[draw=blue] at (2*\j-1,-1) {\k};
}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last column to get the correct number:

```
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm]
       % some styles
       \tikzset{
          box/.style={
          regular polygon,
          regular polygon sides=6,
          minimum size=10mm,
          inner sep=0mm,
          outer sep=0mm,
          rotate=0,
          draw
          }
        }
      \foreach \i in {0,...,1}
        \foreach \j in {0,...,2} {
          \node[box] at (2*\i-1,2*\j-1) {};
          \node[box] at (2*\i,2*\j) {};
          }
      \foreach \j in {0,...,2} {
        \node[box] at (3,2*\j-1) {};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Please extend your answer to be a full example others can copy and compile

Comment: The same shape is achieved as my shape.

Answer (score 0):

The code compiles only after using

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
```

though only

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometry}
```

is available as a choice in the drop down -- and the code will not compile with `geometry`

So is that a bug?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[x=7.5mm,y=4.34mm]
    % some styles
    \tikzset{
      box/.style={
      regular polygon,
      regular polygon sides=6,
      minimum size=10mm,
      inner sep=0mm,
      outer sep=0mm,
      rotate=0,
      draw
      }
    }
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
      \foreach \j in {0,...,2} {
        \node[box] at (2*\i-1,2*\j-1) {};
        \node[box] at (2*\i,2*\j) {};
      }
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```